# JavaScript - How can I use an alert when an image has reached the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, alert, onkeydown, onkeyup

i'm new into programming and I was trying to make an sort of race with a rocket. The rocket has to reach the top of the page and when it has reached the top of the page I want an alert to come out(?). What is the best of way doing this? Thanks in advance!

Ive edited my post, I used the "if" just under my function downpressed.. But it doesnt work.

```
    function leftArrowPressed() {
        var element = document.getElementById("image1");
        element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
        }

        function rightArrowPressed() {
        var element = document.getElementById("image1");
        element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 5 + 'px';

        }

        function upArrowPressed() {
        var element = document.getElementById("image1");
        element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
        }

        function downArrowPressed() {
        var element = document.getElementById("image1");
        element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
        }




        function moveSelection(evt) {

            if(parseInt(element.style.top)==0)
            {
                alert("some text there");
            }
            switch (evt.keyCode) {
                case 37:
                leftArrowPressed();
                break;
                case 39:
                rightArrowPressed();
                break;
                case 38:
                upArrowPressed();
                break;
                case 40:
                downArrowPressed();
                break;
                }
            };

    function docReady()
    {

      window.addEventListener('keydown', moveSelection);
    }
```

Comment: The code you have here doesn't have anything about the alert you're trying to fire.  Can you try to implement the alert first, and then paste the errors or problems you're seeing?

Comment: I edited my answer. Btw now (after you edited) you have one extraneous "}" after my if

Comment: Nope.. it says "element is not defined". It wont go up/down/left/right anymore..

Comment: Nope still nothing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(parseInt(document.getElementById("image1").style.top)<=0)
{
alert("some text there");
}
```

Place it in `moveSelection()`, before switch.